# can't able to mock a variable while testing

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I am trying testing on node js I want to mock a variable outside of a function that is going to be unit tested.
for example

```
const sample = [];
function uploadDoc {
sample.push('fileLocation')
}
function toSave(){
for (i=0;i<sample.length;i++)
**some process read and access doc
}
```

I am facing issue while unit testing the second function
I have tried rewire npm that is also not working

Answer (score 0):

Programming likes this will work,You should call uploadDoc firstly.

```
const sample = [];
    function uploadDoc {
    sample.push('fileLocation')
}
function toSave(){
    uploadDoc();
    for (var i=0;i<sample.length;i++)
    **some process read and access doc
}
```

Comment: i need to test code with sinon. Both uploadDoc() and toSave() are two different API's

Answer (score 0):

Well, you face challenges to test both functions, then, what you need is to refactor the code. Because I think, your code is not testable.
I give you this long example, which contain both of your functions but testable.

Changes I made for refactor:

1. function uploadDoc now will output an array.
2. function toSave now will require 1 parameter, which is an array.
3. [combine functions into class.](https://refactoring.com/catalog/combineFunctionsIntoClass.html)

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { expect } = require('chai');

const Doc = {
  /**
   * @return array of file location.
   */
  uploadDoc: () => {
    const sample = [];
    sample.push('fileLocation');
    return sample;
  },

  /**
   * @param array samples
   * @return void
   */
  toSave: (samples) => {
    samples.forEach(() => {
      // Some process read and access doc.
    })
  },
}

/**
 * This is for example purposes.
 * @return void.
 */
function integrationBothFunction () {
  const samples = Doc.uploadDoc();
  Doc.toSave(samples);
}

describe('Unit Test', function () {
  it('uploadDoc fn', function () {
    const result = Doc.uploadDoc();
    // You expect the result to be an array.
    expect(result).to.be.an('array');
  });
  it('toSave fn', function () {
    const samples = [];
    const spySamples = sinon.spy(samples, 'forEach');
    // Call the function
    Doc.toSave(samples);
    // You expect: there is forEach called for samples.
    expect(spySamples.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
    // Do not forget to restore.
    spySamples.restore();
  });

  it('integrationBothFunction fn', function () {
    // This is just sample to check.
    const testSample = ['x'];
    // Now finally, you can stub uploadDoc.
    // Where real uploadDoc function not get called.
    const stubUploadDoc = sinon.stub(Doc, 'uploadDoc');
    stubUploadDoc.returns(testSample);

    // Spy on toSave fn.
    const spyToSave = sinon.spy(Doc, 'toSave');

    integrationBothFunction();

    // You expect that toSave is processing output from uploadDoc.
    expect(stubUploadDoc.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
    expect(spyToSave.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
    // Check argument toSave.
    const { args } = spyToSave;
    expect(args).to.have.lengthOf(1);
    expect(args[0]).to.have.lengthOf(1);
    expect(args[0][0]).to.include(testSample[0]);
    // Restore spy and stub.
    stubUploadDoc.restore();
    spyToSave.restore();
  });
});
```

I you run using mocha:

```
$ npx mocha stackoverflow.js 


  Unit Test
    ✓ uploadDoc fn
    ✓ toSave fn
    ✓ integrationBothFunction fn


  3 passing (13ms)
$
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Both uploadDoc() and toSave() are two different API's  already returning response to front end @andreyunugro

Comment: Can you explain more related to: _two different API_ or _already returning response to front end_? You can edit your question for clarity and add more complete example if possible.